# selenium shows data: and within a fraction of second we can see the website loading and the authentication popup, it instantly closes and shows data:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a jsp website which a popup authentication using selenium. (If I open python.org It opens without any issues)
As I run the script
First I can see data:, in the tab
Then its shows the website which I want only for a fraction of second and switches back to showing data:,

I can see below error in the log file
2023-04-27 16:09:00,120 Authentication Failed: Check the URL or Network
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/demo_workspace/wfs/wfs_ocp/LegacyOasis/dev/sanity/ansible/url/Framework.py", line 99, in authentication
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
File "/app/demo_workspace/pythonvirtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

I tried the following code :
 `driver.get(url) driver.back() wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) wait.until(EC.alert_is_present()) alert = Alert(driver) alert.send_keys('usename' + "\n" + 'password') alert.accept()`